# javascript - unpause an iframe after stopping it with "window.frames[0].stop()"

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a play/pause button for my iframe. This is what I have so far:

```
    <iframe src="full\test.html" width="250" height="150" style="border: none!important"></iframe>
    <button onclick="javascript:(window.frames[0].stop())">Pause</button>
    <button onclick="javascript:(window.frames[0].play())">Play</button>
```

The first one, "stop", works fine. But I can't figure out how to make the iframe play again after I stop it. How do I make play it again after pausing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each frame in the `window.frames` array is a `window` object for its respective frame ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)). Looking at the [MDN reference for the `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), there's no method which allows a window to be "restarted" after being `.stop()`'ed. Stopping a window is a permanent action until the next reload.

So there's no `.play()` or equivalent method for frames.